# RFBVBIC2 Updating program documentation when implementing SAP note 1737484

Tags: abap, sap-erp

we updated Report RFBVBIC2 (Transaction Code BIC2) implementing SAP Note 1737484. Furthermore we found a zip file "`RFBVBIC2-ITF.zip`" in the attachment section.

The program documentation wasn't updated by implementing the SAP Note.

Trying to update the program documentation manually we were asked to "Create a Modification", give a Modification Name and choose between "Template Type" "Original Text" and  "Template (with Headers)".

When doing so the new documentation (additionally: only available in german) will overlay the old one and no program documentation will be available in any other language.

**My question:** What is the right way to implement such a program documentation update?

Thank you!

Comment: I would say if there is little value to your users (I.E. you don't have any German users) then ignore the documentation update. It will be delivered with a support package at some point, and in the mean time it does not offer you any benefit if it is just a documentation upgrade.

Comment: We do have German users. Our problem is that the english (and any other languages) documentation will be gone once we update the documentation by overlayering it... Is there no standard way to include the documentation in the implementation of the note?